# how to pass html string into message body

Tags: iphone

I want to send particular message to other people via email and sms option. the email portion work perfectly but i don't know how to pass a html string into message body.
for message, I am use MFMessageComposeViewController

and the string is like

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>Map of %@</p><table><tbody><tr valign='top'><td><b>Place Name:</b></td><td>%@</td></tr><tr valign='top'><td><b>Country Name:</b></td><td>%@</td></tr><tr valign='top'><td><b>Area Name:</b></td><td>%@</td></tr><tr valign='top'><td><b>Latitude:</b></td><td>%@</td></tr><tr valign='top'><td><b>Longitude:</b></td><td>%@</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@,%@</a><BR></BR>", [dict objectForKey:@"name"],[dict objectForKey:@"name"], [dict objectForKey:@"country"], [dict objectForKey:@"area"], [dict objectForKey:@"lat"], [dict objectForKey:@"long"],[dict objectForKey:@"lat"], [dict objectForKey:@"long"], [dict objectForKey:@"lat"],[dict objectForKey:@"long"]];
```

how to pass this string into setBody of message controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have assigned a delegate object to your `MFMessageComposeViewController` instance?. The delegate must conform to the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

To setup the initial content of the message use the `body` property.

Here is an example:

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"48151623"];  
    picker.body = @"We either live together... or die alone.";

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

Comment: i have assign all this thing. my question is, i want to pass above emailBody string in picker.body which is in HTML format.

Comment: Remember this is an SMS, only 140 characters are allowed.

Comment: To pass emailBody to picker.body you just type picker.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...", ..., ...];

Comment: thanx, so there is a no way to direct pass html in message. can you tell me, is it possible to write sms in the same manner as above html format output?

Comment: No, it isn't. SMS consist of a string of 140 non-formatted characters.